# Read the binary data of a file, rather than the text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I want to post a file to an API, and I need to post the binary data, not the text.

How can I do that?

I'm reading the text of the file like this:

```
Paperclip.io_adapters.for(jobfile).read
```

but I need the binary data of the file instead of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `file.ext` with the name of the file you want to read from.

```
file = File.binread("file.ext")
bits = file.unpack("B*")[0]

puts bits

=> 0101111101011011100011100001
```